# Is it possible to use the same key-binding for two different packages based on the file extension?

Tags: atom-editor

I use the atom-runner package, which runs scripts when I click alt+x:

[image]

Now, I also installed the gpp-compiler package, which runs c++ files when I click F5:

[image]

It is confusing to have two different key-bindings for running. I would like to use alt+x both for gpp-compiler and for atom-runner, based on the file: if it's a c/c++ file then run gpp-compiler, otherwise run atom-runner.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck. I was doing something similar to this recently and thought that this could be done.

I've made an Atom package to do what you're looking for. You can find it at https://atom.io/packages/multi-hotkey. The default hotkey is Ctrl-M.

Currently only one hotkey is possible, but with customization available for four different user-inputted file extensions and corresponding commands, and a final command for anything not matching the preceding extensions.

Comment: Looks good! Now it could be really helpful to make it configurable. I.e., make a configuration file where you can map key + filename pattern (regular expression) to an action.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I've updated the package so it is customizable, and edited the answer to reflect that. If that answers your question please accept and upvote.